# Why axios post in react is not read by the node server, when params are sent as object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The params are sent. I can see the endpoint triggered, and dev tools display them. However, query params are not received by the server or interpreted incorrectly. 
Simple `axios.post`:

```
async function login(username, password) {
    return await axios.post(LOGIN_URL, {
            username,
            password
        },
    );
}
```

This situation is completely different if I'm just writing the query by hand, everything is received:

```
axios.post(LOGIN_URL + `?username=${username}&password:${password}`);
```

I want to use my bodyParser in educational purposes.
Interpretation is as simple as possible with just 4 logs:

```
function bodyParser (req, res, next) {
    const body = url.parse(req.url).query;

    console.log(req.url); // /auth
    console.log(req.query); // {}
    console.log(req.body); // undefined
    console.log(req.params); // {}

    res.body = body;
    next();
}
```

The app:

```
import express from 'express';

import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from './middlewares';

import auth from "./routes/auth.route";

const app = express();

app.use('/', cors());
app.use('/', bodyParser);

app.use('/auth', auth);

export default app;
```

Comment: are you using express?

Comment: Try req.body in Node to see when you send as a data payload. So console.log(req.body) when you're using axiost.post with the second arg being an object.

Comment: **Never** put the username and password in the URL.

Comment: @ChrisGong yep, sure.

Comment: @Brant it is empty every time for some reason but I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: @EmileBergeron sure, it was only for experiment.

Comment: @Animus, could you add the express route that uses the function you have above?

Comment: @ChrisGong updated the question. bodyParser is called on root, so every other route will have body of the req.

Comment: Hey @Animus could you see if my answer below is of any help?

Comment: Sure, thanks @ChrisGong I'll check it in a couple hours!

Comment: As I explained lower, the answer is not working with a custom bodyParser, which was the idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
async function login(username, password) {
return await axios.post(LOGIN_URL, {
        username,
        password
    },
);
}
```

That's sending username and password in the req.body. So in Node, you need to be checking req.body

A Url like so:

```
http://someurl.com/api?username=a&password=b
```

You pick those variables up in req.query.

A Url like so:

```
http://someurl.com/api/people/some_id_here
```

You pick that ID up in req.params.

Comment: The thing is, with normal payload, I have epmty everything: url, query, body, params. Since my function were sening it to req.body, something is still wrong.

Comment: i suspect you need the xpress body parse middlewaye to do what Brent is suggsting
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an issue with how you're calling `axios.post(...)`. Assuming that when you call `axios` this way and it works:

```
axios.post(LOGIN_URL + `?username=${username}&password:${password}`);
```

The `username` and `password` variables passed to `axios.post(LOGIN_URL, {username, password})` are string variables. Therefore, you forgot to key the values like so,

```
async function login(username, password) {
    return await axios.post(LOGIN_URL, {
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        },
    );
}
```

Now in your `bodyParser` function, you should be able to access these variables passed in via `req.params.username` and `req.params.password`.

Comment: Params are empty and variables are undefined.

Comment: @Animus are the parameters successfully getting to the `login` function?

Comment: Sure, they are sent, and It is visible from the dev tools. 
The thing is, I didn't know from which variable of the `req` object I could parse them. 
And I didn't want to use body-parser, since it had some issues and now it is deprecated.

Comment: A way out for me was to use: axios.post(LOGIN_URL, {username, password}) and parse data with express.json(). However, I wanted to parse it myself. 
It might be, that I need to ask another question.